# Android Started Service: Does a "download operation" return a result to the caller?

Tags: android, android-service

This [Android docs about Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) says in the sub-section named "Started" (that is a Start Service, in contrast to a Bound Service),

> "Usually, a started service performs a single operation and does not
>   return a result to the caller. For example, it might download or
>   upload a file over the network. "

But doesn't a download operation return a result (that is the downloaded file) to the caller?

For example a service which downloads an `mp3` file from the network is actually return a result which is the `mp3` file, isn't it?

Comment: yup ,interesting thing !!! never think about that ..want to know ans .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `started service` is like a bad slave for you. when you ask it to do something he does it but he dose not return actual result for you. For example you ask: "please give me some water!" and instead of bringing a glass of water he goes and prepares a glass of water but instead of giving it to you he just shout at you "I put your glass of water on the table so go and drink it.". `Bound service` is like a waiter in a restaurant. you ask him I want a glass of water and he goes and comes back with a glass of water.

So now it is up to you to judge. Dose the slave bring what you are asking? I will say no, he dose what I ask but he just tell me how I can get the prepared result.

Dose the waiter bring what you are asking? Yes, surely.

Can `started service` bring result in any way? yes he can but his ability is limited to all objects you can pass by intents because in order to tell you that I have done he must use broadcast.

Comment: your service apparently uses a broadcast to warn you. note that is not a requirement. It could simply put the glass on the table for you to discover by yourself and disappear.

Comment: @njzk2 yes you are right but I think the context of OP is focus on getting the result.